# Send result of powershell script in file

Tags: powershell

Am I doing something wrong with the following code :
if yes, please, how can i fix it ?

```
$currentDir = Get-Location
$output = Write-Host "$currentDir\computedMD5.txt"
Get-FileHash $currentDir\* -Algorithm MD5 | Format-List | Out-File -FilePath $output
```

Comment: You should check each value you get from your code lines. What do you expect, what do you get. This should be included in *each StackOverflow question*. Hint: please explain what do you expect as value of `$output` and why that value should be returned by `Write-Host`.

Comment: with the following line in powershell "Get-FileHash $currentDir\* -Algorithm MD5 | Format-List" i've got exactly what i want, i'm just trying to create a script to send the result in a file ./computedMD5.txt
Sorry, u right, it was not really clear in the question

Comment: Yea. And you shouldn't extend your question in a comment. Always update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess as you don't explain what exactly you're trying to do but regardless you're overcomplicating things:

```
$currentDir = Get-Location
Get-FileHash "$currentDir\*" -Algorithm MD5 | Out-File -FilePath "$currentDir\computedMD5.txt"
```

It's probably not a good idea to use a wildcard for input though unless you specifically code for multiple matches. So a better appproach if you have multiple files is as follows:

```
$currentDir = Get-Location
Get-ChildItem -Path $currentDir | ForEach-Object {
Get-FileHash $_.FullName -Algorithm MD5 | Out-File -FilePath ($_.FullName + "_computedMD5.txt")
}
```

Comment: You already marked the wildcard as problematic. I would emphasize this. With the current approach you get a non-reproducible result of the output file. The output file is included in the wildcard. The stored MD5 checksum for the result file with change the result file in each run.

Comment: Good call, answer edited

Answer (score 0):

When trying the same code (ofcourse adjusted to my folders) I get an error about the target file can't be read.

I then tried encapsulating the main operations in brackets and all was fine and dandy:

```
( Get-FileHash * | Format-List ) | Out-File t.txt -Force
```

I'm no expert on PS pipelines, but I suspect that the problem is something like a racing condition, that the target file is opened before the filehash is calculated. When using the brackets, the code inside is run first, and then outputs that result to the pipeline.

Although, I can only guess this is a solution, since there are no errors in the question to guide us to what is actually happening for you.